# openssl "unable to find 'distinguished_name' in config"

Tags: openssl

I get the following error from `openssl req`:

```
unable to find 'distinguished_name' in config
problems making Certificate Request
41035:error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-52.30.1/src/crypto/conf/conf_lib.c:329:group=req name=distinguished_name
```

My understanding is that this is the "Subject" that it can't find… however, I *am* specifying that:

```
openssl req -new \
    -key "$PRIVATE_KEY" \
    -sha256 \
    -config "$OPTIONS_FILE" \
    -subj "/C=US/ST=California/L=San Francisco/O=ACME, Inc./CN=*.*.$DOMAIN/" \
    -out "$CSR_FILENAME"
```

The manual's only suggestion is that the config file doesn't exist; I can `cat "$OPTIONS_FILE"`, so it's definitely there, and the error isn't preceded by the error the manual notes it would be preceded by if this were the case, so I'm pretty sure `openssl` sees the config file.

My config file contains the following:

```
[req]
req_extensions = v3_req

[ v3_req ]
# Extensions to add to a certificate request
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = *.*.example.com
```

…which is pretty much [literally the example in the docs](http://wiki.cacert.org/FAQ/subjectAltName).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Minor note: the subjectAltName specified here, `*.*.example.com`, is invalid. (You can only have 1 `*`, and only in the leftmost component.) This doesn't relate to the problem here, but don't c/p blindly.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

*Near as I can tell*, `-config` is overriding some sort of internal config; if you see the "EXAMPLES" section for [the man page for openssl req](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/req.html), it shows an example of a config file with `distinguished_name` in it. On a hunch, I added the following to my config:

```
[req]
…
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name

[req_distinguished_name]
# empty.
```

Thus, my entire config looked something like

```
[req]
req_extensions = v3_req
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name

[req_distinguished_name]

[v3_req]
# Extensions to add to a certificate request
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = *.*.${DOMAIN}
```

(Note that here, `${DOMAIN}` is not literal; you should replace it with your DNS domain name; I create this file in a `bash` script with `cat >"$OPTIONS_FILE" <<EOF`, followed by the above, followed by `EOF`)

`openssl req … -subj <my subject> -config <that file> …` then took my subject from the command line. For those interested, the entire command ended up looking like:

```
openssl req -new \
    -key "$PRIVATE_KEY" \
    -sha256 \
    -config "$OPTIONS_FILE" \
    -subj "/C=US/ST=California/L=San Francisco/O=My Company, Inc./CN=*.*.$DOMAIN/" \
    -out "$CSR_FILENAME"
```

As of this posting, my understanding is that SHA-1 is deprecated¹ for X.509 certs, hence `-sha256` (which is an undocumented flag…), and subjectAltName is becoming required², hence the need for the config. The only additional gotcha that I know of in order to generate a best-practice CSR to the above is that you should use a RSA key size of at least 2048 bits (if you're using RSA, which I am); you *must* specify the size to the `openssl genrsa` command as the current default is insecure.

<sub>¹While not broken at the time I'm writing this, people feel that it is only a matter of time. See ["Gradually sunsetting SHA1"](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2014/09/gradually-sunsetting-sha-1.html)</sub>

<sub>²Using CN for the domain-name is no longer recommended; I'm not sure when/if browsers are planning to deprecate this. "Move away from including and checking strings that look like domain names in the subject's Common Name.", [RFC 6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125#section-1.5)</sub>
<sub>Note: I am less certain about the "correct" value of `keyUsage`.</sub>

Comment: See my note on the question; the config in this answer is invalid, in that `*.*.example.com` is not valid (you can't have multiple `*`s); c/p-ers beware.

Comment: Empty section `req_distinguished_name` isn't accepted by openssl 1.1.0f, so you have to have at least `countryName_default` there (refer to [Openssl.conf Walkthru](https://www.phildev.net/ssl/opensslconf.html)).

Comment: Where is this config file?

Answer (score 20):

I had the same problem and found the response here:

https://www.citrix.com/blogs/2015/04/10/how-to-create-a-csr-for-a-san-certificate-on-netscaler/

The config file looks like this:

```
[req]
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions = v3_req
prompt = no
[req_distinguished_name]
C = US
ST = VA
L = SomeCity
O = MyCompany
OU = MyDivision
CN = www.company.com
[v3_req]
keyUsage = keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = www.company.com
DNS.2 = company.com
DNS.3 = www.company.net 
DNS.4 = company.net
```

And then:

```
openssl req -new -key private.key -sha256 -nodes -config openssl.conf -out certificate.csr
```

Comment: This would work too; I was specifying the subject on the command line (as that was simpler for my use case); this just moves it to the config file. More, my question related to OpenSSL complaining that the subject couldn't be found when, in fact, it had been specified.

Comment: I am not sure if this solution works - in Windows it's constantly reporting "Unable to find distinguished_name in the config" tried everything.

Comment: The `req_distinguished_name` section can be left blank. What it does is to specify the template of labels of the required field names, which can be overwritten by `-subj= /C=xx/ST=xx/L=xx/O=xx/OU=xx/CN=xx` etc., it is, not to assign those field values though.

Answer (score 5):

For me this error seem to be caused by incorrect path creation when running the command in Windows Server 2012, `C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin`

```
openssl req -new -sha256 -key private.pem -out example.csr
```

which output a non-blocking error before asking for pass phare:

> Can't open C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\SSL/openssl.cnf for
>   reading, No s uch file or directory

Clearly, the path is invalid because of the wrong slash, so config file must be explicitly appended in the command line:

```
openssl req -new -sha256 -key private.pem -config openssl.cfg -out example.csr
```

Comment: This worked for me, nice and clean. Thanks a lot!

Comment: While this no doubt solves your problem, it doesn't relate to the original question aside from having to do w/ OpenSSL. (This might be better as a separate question/answer.)

Comment: This fixed my issue with "openssl unable to find 'distinguished_name' in config” thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This similar error:

> $ openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout _key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365 -nodes
>   You are about to be asked to enter information that will be
>   incorporated into your certificate request. What you are about to
>   enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN. There are quite
>   a few fields but you can leave some blank For some fields there will
>   be a default value, If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
>   ----- Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:problems making Certificate Request

(Ubuntu 17.04) meant "you need to add

`-subj "/C=US/ST=California/L=San Francis co/O=ACME, Inc./CN=*.*.$DOMAIN/"`

to the command line" FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible issue can be special (invisible) UTF-8 characters. Check your file using

```
cat -v $OPTIONS_FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, run `/bin/openssl.exe` as Administrator.

Comment: Not sure why was this downgraded, but with my experience, this was the problem solver. I had the same error on my terminal, perhaps it's a generic error. Opening it as Administrator(which I forgot to do in first place) solved it.

Comment: How to do this?

Comment: Right click on the the file and use the Open as Administrator option.

Answer (score 0):

Just 2 cents. I had this weird error message, when in `.bashrc` there was set another

```
export OPENSSL_CONF=somelocalpath/openssl.conf
```

thus default config was not working!

quick check is to manually add `-config=/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` to command line, and if it start working, just look at your environment.